# Change all URLS when Moving from Development to Live

Tags: php, html

I am sure that this is a repost but I cannot find a question the same as what I want to find out. Essentially, whenever I am working offline, all URIs that I use across the site refer to offline locations eg 127.0.0.1/home.html however, when I go to upload the site, these URIs need to be changed to their equivalents eg example.com/home.html and I either need to go through all of the pages and update these references or use some php to insert the correct address at every point where an address is used. At the minute I am using something like this:

Top of every page:

```
<?php $offline = false; ?>
```

Link:

```
<a href="<?php echo ($offline ? '127.0.0.1' : 'example.com'); ?>/home.html">Home</a>
```

But this seems like a poor way to achieve something which should be relatively simple. What is the standard way of keeping these references up to date. I considered using relative links everywhere but that proved to have problems (for example view includes don't work correctly) and I tried setting the `base` `href` to the homepage but that threw up other problems.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you __should__ drop it all to give /home.html, ie stay on current domain

Comment: OR define a constant with `define('DOMAIN', '127.0.0.1');` and then <a href="`<?php echo DOMAIN; ?>`/home.html">home</a>

Comment: Top of every page: `<?php include_once('config.php'); ?>` and put all your settings in that file instead. That way you only have to amend one file to change the entire site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A neat way that I have found to resolve this issue is to amend your HOSTS file so that it points example.com to 127.0.0.1 so that you can refer to example.com everywhere but be redirected to 127.0.0.1 until your development has finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
$server=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
// Local
if(strstr($server,'127.0.0'))
{
    define('ROOT_PATH','http://127.0.0.1/');
}
// Server
else
{
    define('ROOT_PATH','http://www.yoursite.com/');
}
```

Put this code in php file and **include in every page**.

And then:

```
<a href="<?php echo ROOT_PATH?>/home.html">Home</a>
```

In this case you can put your files in folder too, for example:

```
define('ROOT_PATH','http://www.yoursite.com/mysite/');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Waygood suggested, it sounds like you need to change your paths from absolute to either site root relative or relative paths.  Example: 127.0.0.1/home.html would become just /home.html if using site root relative.  Alternatively, if there's a reason why you must include absolute paths, you can set an environment variable on the server or a PHP constant that indicates the environment type and toggle links based on this value.  Using environment variables has the added benefit of being able to keep the exact same code base on your dev and production machines and not having to resort to host or IP detection.  Here's an example from zend framework's docs guide that I use:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV',
    (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

From: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is using relative paths.

For files in the same directory you'd use ./ and for files above that directory use ../ This works for anchors in HTML and requires and includes in PHP.